# Equivalence problem and Maurer-Cartan structure equations

Tags: differential-geometry, pullback

I am reading a proposition. The proposition is as follows:

Let $M$ and $\bar{M}$ be two manifold, with $\{\mu_i\}$ and $\{\bar{\mu}_i\}$ co-frame, respectively. And there is an diffeomorphism s.t. $\phi^*d\bar{\mu}=d\mu$. The Maurer-Cartan equations for $M$ and $\bar{M}$ is

‎$$
‎\mathrm{d}\mu^k=\sum_{i<j}C_{ij}^k(x)\mu^i \wedge \mu^j‎,
‎$$
and

$$
‎\mathrm{d}\bar{\mu}^k=\sum_{i<j}\bar{C}_{ij}^k(x)\bar{\mu}^i \wedge \bar{\mu}^j‎,
$$

then by ‎$\phi^*\mathrm{d}\bar{\mu}=\mathrm{d}\phi^*\bar{\mu}$‎, they are equivalent if and only if
$$
‎\bar{C}_{ij}^k(\phi(x))=C_{ij}^k(x).
$$

My question is "How it is proved $\bar{C}_{ij}^k(\phi(x))=C_{ij}^k(x)$ iff two manifold are equivalent"?

Comment: This needs a lot more details. Start by defining what it means for $\phi\colon M\to \bar M$ to be an "equivalence."

Comment: Have you started with [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_equivalence_method) and a source like [Gardner](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611970135)? Bryant, Chern, Gardner, Goldschmidt, and Griffiths's [Exterior Differential Systems](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-9714-4) is quite a step up. Perhaps Bryant's lectures [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/~bryant/MSRI_Lectures.pdf) will be a more suitable starting place.

Comment: Bryant's lecture notes are an excellent resource---I used them to learn some of the subject myself.